# JQuery range slider tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here is my html:

```
<div class="col-md-4"><input autocomplete="off" type="range" min="1" max="20" value="10" id="agriculture" oninput="display(id);"></div>
```

I need to display tooltip on moving the slider.

How can i achieve this?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iviknesh/H2FZQ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest form of popover that will not require any CSS / JS is the title attribute, which can be set on just about anything!

```
<input ... title="Hey, you should drag me!"/>
```

Hover over it for about 2 seconds and it will show up.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2FZQ/1/)

---

If you are looking for something a bit more responsive, the easiest way to do this will be to incorporate the [**Bootstrap Tooltips API**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), which has lots of code already written that can put any content you want `[above|below|left|right]` any element.

Comment: @Ruddy It disappears when you move your mouse away or click, but it will show again if you hover for another 2 seconds.

Comment: @Vikneshwaren Ah so you want a fancy slider ;) Ok then. BTW to do inline links, you do `[display text](url)`

Comment: @David I know how it works lol. It doesn't reappear for me after moving the slider. Chrome 33.

Comment: Please someone could edit my fiddle or set up a new fiddle with working one, please

Comment: @Ruddy Yeah, you have to mouseout and hover again.

Comment: @David Again, I know how it works. It does not work.

Comment: Well on my Chrome 33 it *does work* ;) Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @David Very odd, works when I did it in FF.. Also seems to work when I click off the `input` but `mouseout` doesn't seem to do the trick. No idea.

Comment: @David 
Please edit my fiddle or set up a new one and help me please

Comment: @Vikneshwaren Just use the bootstrap API I linked to. It will be much easier than creating a whole new one from scratch.

Comment: where have u linkd it ? @David

Comment: @Vikneshwaren You only added the CSS file. You need the JS too, and the tooltip needs to go inside a `$(function(){});` I'll put one together.

Comment: @David What should i do if i want to change the text as the slider gets moved?

Comment: Please help.. i need to change the text as the slider gets moved

Answer (score 1):

```
Something like this??
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zu59F/)

updated to your jsfiddle